# How to print continue on ending of ever page except last in Crystal Report XI?

Tags: vba, vb6, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

[image: Snapshot of Crystal Report]

my detailsection2 is default suppressed,
I want to unsuppress DetailSection2 only when page reaches to an end then again supress on next page
and unsuppress DetailSection3 on last record.

I've managed unsupress DetailSection3 By adding the below formula
(Placed in Supress(No Drill-Down)'s Formula Field)
Formula:
if OnLastRecord then false else true

So Output Will Look Like
------------------Page 1-----------------------
  Name | Amount
  AB11 | 1200
  AB11 | 1200
  Continue......
-----------------Page 1------------------------
-----------------Page 2------------------------
Name | Amount
  AB11 | 1200
  AB11 | 1200
  Gtotal : 4800
-----------------Page 2------------------------

Answer (score 2):

- Move text field (that reads 'continued') to page-footer; add suppression formula for section that reads `OnLastRecord`.
- Move grand total to report-footer section

Comment: This won`t work in subreport because pageFotter will be converted into reportFooter.